# Oracle Pattern Matching(regexp_like) for csv

Tags: regex, oracle11g, filtering

I have a table offer_detail which contains columns like

```
    Offer_ID          Customer_IDS
    EF123             100,200,300   
    EF124             300,700,800
```

I am writing a query which will have `customer id` as a parameter. Based on the `customer_id` the results are to filtered. For example, if the input `customer_id` is 100, I should be getting the all the `offer_id`s that contain the `customer_id` in csv.

I tried using `regexp_like` function

```
select offer_id 
  from offer_detail 
 where regexp_like(customer_ids,':INPUT_PARAMETER')
```

It works fine if the parameter is a single value, If the parameter contains multiple values, then this does not work. Is there any work around? Kindly Help. I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: why don't you split the comma separated values first? so you don't have to use regexp_like, and your query may use an index..

Comment: Do the multiple Customer id values in your Input Parameter concur in the Same Order as tHey do in the cutomer_ids Field? Do they contain extra spaces? Most Important, bonsvr is right, structured values in dB table Attributes is poor Design, customer_ids should be stored in a table of their Own and Be linked to offer_details by means of another m:n-Relation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending multiple parameters using OR operator of RegEx as below

```
select offer_id 
from offer_detail 
where regexp_like(customer_ids,'700|800|200');
```

But again it's a poor design.